# Retain variable value in a code run for next code run

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need to edit/crop sets of pictures in a slide.

I want a system where I display one picture, edit it, then run a macro to "hide" the picture and display the next picture of the set.

I renamed the pictures with this format: "Photo 1", "Photo 2", "Photo 3", ... (Photo & n).

I managed to write a macro that does what I want for the first picture, but then fails from the second picture onward.

```vb
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim n As Long
 
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    n = n + 1
    If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Name = "Photo " & n Then

        ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Photo " & n + 1).Visible = msoCTrue
        ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Visible = msoFalse

    End If
End With
```

The problem lies in the starting condition with `n = n + 1`, because n resets to 0 every time I run the macro.

I am trying to tell Powerpoint that n is the number found in the selected picture's name instead of resetting n to 0 every time.

I also tried using the shape index (since the photos are one after the other), but apparently it's not a good idea since the index is not very "reliable/stable", plus I couldn't find a way to find the index of a shape anyway.

I also tried adding an `Else n = n + 1` condition at the end, but I'm guessing (assuming that's a viable option) it needs another step where it tells the macro to return to the starting point. Last time I tried a "loop" it crashed my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
Dim n as Long
```

use

```
Static n as Long
```

Variables declared as Static retain their value from one invocation of your subroutine to the next.

OR

At the top of the module:

```
Public n as Long
```

That will make it public; it wont' change value until you expressly change it from any subroutine in your code.